# How to setup Eclipse project with two webapps, and also be able to do Hot Swap

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

If a project has two webapps, and both webapps consume the same DAO, Service, etc. sub-projects, whats the best way to setup 'output' folders in Eclipse, so that I can deploy both webapps simultaneously to Jetty/Tomcat, and also be able to debug (with Hot Swap) both?

Is it possible? or should I just make one webapp the 'primary' webapp, and make the secondary webapp consume Jars of DAO and Serice layer? (i.e. only one output folder for the sub-projects).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use two web projects in Eclipse and make them both depend on the service layer, dao project.